# combine all the stubs for methods in one file and then importing it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

i am writing unit test cases and i want to write all my stubs in one file and then import it whenever my unit test case require the stub .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.